# Two modalpopup on a single aspx page

Tags: c#, ajax

I am using two popup extender in my single .aspx page none of the two is getting popped up but when i am removing either of the two one is popping up fine.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" /> 
<asp:Button ID="btnshowpopupisbn" runat="server" style="display:none" />  

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"     runat="server"TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup"
CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"     PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlpopup" >
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>   
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" CssClass="popup" >
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>

 <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server"       TargetControlID="btnshowpopupisbn" PopupControlID="pnlpopupisbn"   cancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"    PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlpopup"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopupisbn" runat="server" CssClass="popup" Visible="False" >
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">


 <ContentTemplate>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: why the panel `pnlpopupisbn` property is `visible=false` ??

Comment: :) yeah..!!! visible=true worked....

Comment: What is your real problem????

Comment: Small mistakes make the problem look bigger, happens with me most of the times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do Panel  Visible="False"

Answer (score 1):

Do not set the property visible to false .set it to true

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to give  the `Visible="False"` property on the panels, it is taken care of when you use  the ModalPopupExtender.
I just tried using 2 modal popups, worked fine.

```
<div>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Popup 1" />
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1"
            TargetControlID="Button1" OkControlID="Button2" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="popup">
            Some Content in Panel 1<br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Popup 2" />
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel2"
            TargetControlID="Button3" OkControlID="Button4" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="popup">
            Some Content in Panel 2<br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```